# How to separate row by tags in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, kaggle

I am trying to analyze the dataset about movies and their genres.
So, to perform my investigation I need to separate every movie by it's tags [image of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXdnV.jpg)
but I don't know how to do it.

In preferred result there will be every movie several times with every it's genres.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: I have just get the answer on my question on other forum. But, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

To split them, we can use that:

`df['genre'] = df['genre'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))`

```
df.explode('genre')
```

It's simpler than I thought :)

Comment: `df['genre'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack()`